# Shorter way to write this SQL query with a 3-way join and a condition

Tags: sql, join

I'm currently learning SQL in the Harvard CS50 online course. The assignment is to write various SQL queries for a database. [Here is a link to the assignment.](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/7/movies/) I'm talking about the 12th query there.

The schema of the database looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE movies (
    id    INTEGER,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    year  NUMERIC,

    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE stars (
    movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    
    FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
);

CREATE TABLE directors (
    movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   
    FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
);

CREATE TABLE ratings (
    movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    rating REAL NOT NULL,
    votes INTEGER NOT NULL,
    
    FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id)
);

CREATE TABLE people (
    id INTEGER,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    birth NUMERIC,
    
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

The goal is to write a SQL query that returns the titles of all movies in which both Johnny Depp and Helena Bonham Carter starred. The query I came up with returns the list of movies for each actor and then uses INTERSECT on both of these lists. This is the query:

```sql
SELECT
    movies.title
FROM
    movies
    JOIN stars  ON movies.id        = stars .movie_id
    JOIN people ON stars .person_id = people.id
WHERE
    people.name = "Johnny Depp"

INTERSECT

SELECT
    movies.title
FROM
    movies
    JOIN stars  ON movies.id        = stars .movie_id
    JOIN people ON stars .person_id = people.id
WHERE
    people.name = "Helena Bonham Carter";
```

The query returns the correct results, however I feel it isn't very elegant or fast. Is there a shorter, more elegant and/or faster way to write this?

Comment: Your query will be slow for many reasons (namely, lack of indexes - you don't even have any `PRIMARY KEY` constraints defined on most of your tables). Your query itself, however, _does_ seem elegant to me, though you can eliminate the repetition of the JOIN criteria with a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
with cte as (
    select
        movie_id,count(p.id) as cnt
    from stars s
    join people p on p.id = s.person_id
    where p.name in (
        "Johnny Depp","Helena Bonham Carter"
    )
    group by movie_id
)
select title
from movies
where id in (
    select movie_id from cte where cnt = 2
)
```

Basically the cte gets the movie ids where the two people are present in the stars table. Then we count that to see where both people are present in the stars table and join it to the movies table to get the actual name. You could probably use 'having' instead also.